# Makefile Absolute Path with colon

Tags: makefile, relative-path, absolute-path, msys

To convert a relative path to an absolute path, I used the relpath / abspath command.
However the result delivers a path with the root directory without the colon `:`.

Example:

> "/c/Users/MyName/Project/SVN/ACC/PCC/HAL/code/include"

I need `c:/Users/MyName/Project/SVN/ACC/PCC/HAL/code/include` so that my code can find the header files.

I'm using make from MSYS 1.0.

Is there any way I can get this result?

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far and where it failed to work as expected?

Comment: "$(realpath ./../../../../../ or "$(abspath ./../../../../../) It generates the path as expected /c/users/Myname/. However I am searching for some method that can generate for me c:/users/Myname

Answer (score 0):

```
winpath_helper=$1:/$(subst ////$1/,,$2)
winpath=$(call winpath_helper,$(word 1,$(subst /, ,$1)),///$1)

ppp:=/c/Users/MyName/Project/SVN/ACC/PCC/HAL/code/include
$(info === $(call winpath,$(ppp)))
```

result:

```
c:/Users/MyName/Project/SVN/ACC/PCC/HAL/code/include
```

This implies that the input is corerct format; if it is not result of $realpath or $abspath on MSYS, the make can crash.